# What is the official java client for Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have found the documentation for official java client getting 404 error when checking on ksql documentation. Can anyone give me link to where to find java repository and documentation for java client for kafka.

Comment: KsqlDB uses the official Java client. It isn't the official one itself

Answer (score 2):

You can find the official repository for Kafka on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/kafka

The Kafka website has the official documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/

Comment: Specifically https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#api